# WP composer installation and Unistallation with CLI

Tags: wordpress, composer-php, wordpress-theming

I have tried to make a theme, pre-packed from **underscore.me**, then I have gone the theme root folder. Then command: `composer install` then I have found 1 folder (**vendor**) and **composer.lock** file. Then I can check my project with `composer lint:wpcs` this command. Now, feel that this vendor & composer.lock file is unnecessary for me.

How can I uninstall them with command line without `sudo rm -rf 'bla bla'` this command.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "uninstall"? If there are files that are not neccessary, why not simply delete them?

Comment: Is it enough if I delete those?

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve

Comment: I want to kmow learn with CLI, so maked this question.

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to learn? Where are you stuck? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Thanks Already Solved